# Concatenate String + date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation

I have the following data:

```
KEY        ID         DATE
123456789  09BA2038   01-01-2017
```

And I would like to concatenate it, but keep the original format of the date. When I try:

```
CONCAT(Key, '-', ID, '-', DATE)
```

it gives me an output of

```
123456789-09BA2038-Jan 01 2017 11:00AM
```

But I would like the output to be

```
123456789-09BA2038-01-01-2017
```

Comment: convert your date to a sting in the correct Format first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the date, I am guessing you want the format mm-dd-yyyy, if so:

```
CONCAT([key],'-',[ID],'-',CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [DATE], 110))
```

If you want dd-mm-yyyy it is:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [DATE], 105)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're using SQL Server 2012 or newer, then you can use [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql) to change a date or datetime into a varchar with the format of your liking.

```sql
select CONCAT([Key],'-',ID,'-',FORMAT([DATE],'MM-dd-yyyy')) as Key2
from (values (123456789,'09BA2038',convert(date,'2017-01-15',126))) v([Key],ID,[DATE]);
```

Result:

```
Key2
123456789-09BA2038-01-15-2017
```

Or you could use [CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) instead using the 110 style for the USA date format.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an explicit convert to get the date format you want.

In this case `CONCAT(Key, '-', ID, '-', convert(varchar(10),DATE,105))` should work fine.

You can find the full list of formats here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql

Comment: Thank you, the list was very helpful indeed!

Answer (score 0):

Try `CONCAT(Key, '-', ID, '-', CONVERT(varchar(10),DATE, 110))`. The `110` tells SQL Server to format the date as 'mm-dd-yyyy' (US style).

For more information about this look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql).

Niels

Answer (score -1):

I think not using concat is better in this situation
like this:

```
select convert(nvarchar(100),KEY)+'-'+convert(nvarchar(100),ID)+'-'+convert(nvarchar(100),DATE)
from tableName
```

Comment: This wouldn't give the format required in the question.

Comment: @Leonidas199x why? datatype is not important when you are concating your string, it will be nvarchar in my quert, and it is exactly  like the format that he wanted. I'll be glad if I'm wrong you convince me, thanks!

Comment: There is a specific format of the date being asked for in the question, your answer does not give it. Run this and it is obvious: SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100),GETDATE()),CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),110)

Comment: Why would you rather only use `+`?  A CONCAT seems better when some of the values can allow NULL's and you still want to return something.  F.e. `select concat('x','-y'+null) as v2`

Comment: @LukStorms I don't think `concat` is any different from `+` in this sense, and neither should rely on concatenating a `null` yielding anything other than `null` because the alternative is (horrible, non-ANSI, and) deprecated: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-concat-null-yields-null-transact-sql

Comment: To me, a CONCAT seems more standard than the  + concatination operator. :-) And the CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL setting only affects the behaviour of `+`, not the CONCAT function. But yeah, the name of that to-be-deprecated setting can be misleading O_o

Comment: @Leonidas199x yes i get your point but for this query that asked in question this will not happend I think
try this:
`
declare @date date
set @date='01-01-2017'
select CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100),@date)
`
I think in his table date shows as 01-01-2017 but when he concated date shows as Jan 01 2017 11:00AM

Comment: @dood that is a presumption you should have stated in your answer. It is stored as a date, and therefore the conversion would be needed.